# Update TableView from async api source

Tags: uitableview, swift3, nstableview

I have an application where I have to connect to a REST API.  It pulls that data and updates the datasource that is an NSDirectory, but since the request is in a main.async dispatch queue it will trigger the reloadData before the data has been updated.  Is there any way to get it to request the data after the datasource is completely updated?

Comment: need to see your code before anyone can realistically help you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a completion handler associated with your REST API call so that you can call reloadData after you've fetched and processed the requested information.